# Which atmosphere model(s) put the upper end of the tropopause isothermal layer at 25 km and why?

Tags: temperature, atmosphere-modelling, troposphere, stratosphere

The International and U.S. Standard atmospheres have a layer between 11 km (36,000 ft) and 20 km (66,000 ft) where the temperature is constant with altitude. This includes older versions of the U.S. Standard atmosphere. However, sometimes I come across temperature models that maintain the temperature constant up to 25 km (82,000 ft) and begin an increase in temperature above that altitude. What models are these and why are they different from the (usual) standard atmospheres?